# gnuplot scientific notation in axis label

Tags: label, gnuplot, scientific-notation

I would like to save some space in my plot by moving the exponent of the scientific notation from the y tics to the y label. Here an example script:

```
reset
set term png
set out 'sci.png'

set xlabel 'X'; set ylabel 'Y /10^%S'
set xtics out; set mxtics; set ytics out; set mytics

set format y '%.0s*10^%S'; set ytics add ('0' 0)

plot exp(x) w l
unset out
```

[image]

Is there any way I can use the [scientific power](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node184.html) `%S` in the y label?

Answer (score -1):

Did you notice that the '%' in the ylabel is in superscript. In a text string, the first character after ^ will be in superscript. If you need more than one character in superscript, put them around curly brackets. Try this:

```
set ylabel 'Y /10^{3}'
```

However, it is more standard, rather than divide the ylabel by a number, to include units and multiply the units by a number. I would do either of these, for example, if the units were meters (m).

```
set ylabel 'Y (m x 10^3)'
```

or

```
set ylabel 'Y (km)'
```

Comment: You missed the point: the question is about using the `%S` format in ylabel, which is not possible.

Comment: Thank you @dan-sp but that is not exactly my question. @Christoph, so it is not possible to use `%S` outside the `set format` command? Not even with any kind of function?